# One route works and one doesn't

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just started to learn react. I have an **App** component that renders **Home** and **Header**. **Home** renders an input and a button, if the button was clicked and the input is valid I want to render the component **Dashboard** and set my route to '/dashboard'. The component **Dashboard** is never rendered and the URL is not changing also. I don't understand why component **Home** renders and **Dashboard** doesn't and what should I change in my return statement in **Home** component.

This is in my **App** component

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
            <Header />
            <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

This is in my **Home** component

```
render() {
    if(this.state.clicked) {
        if (this.state.valid)
            return (
                <div>
                    <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={Dashboard}/>
                </div>
            )
        else
            this.change; //change set clicked to false
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this)}/>
            <button onClick={this.login}>LOGIN</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC there is an extension that is a "Route Debugger". Maybe [such a thing exists for React](https://gist.github.com/adjavaherian/aa48e78279acddc25315), too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home component will only render a route if the url is met.  In your home component, you are not changing the components URL you are just telling it to render the dashboard component if the url matches the path for it.  I think what you're looking to use is react-routers [Redirect component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).  This component will redirect you to a different component when it is called.  However, this means you will have to define the Dashboard component somewhere else.  In your case your **Home** component would look something like:

```
render() {
if(this.state.clicked) {
    if (this.state.valid)
        return (
            <Redirect to='/Dashboard' />
        )
    else
        this.change; //change set clicked to false
}
return (
    <div>
        <input onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this)}/>
        <button onClick={this.login}>LOGIN</button>
    </div>
);
}
```

And your App component would have a route set up for Dashboard

```
render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={'/Dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
}
```

Comment: I tried this already (forgot to mention) but later I would need to pass props to Dashboard, can I do this with Redirect?

Comment: Yes, you can write your redirect component like so: 
    `<Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { referrer: currentLocation }
    }}/>`

Comment: Also, if you're trying to only allow a user to view a component if they're signed in I would suggest creating a higher order component to render a PrivateRoute component that takes in a route and only renders it if a condition (such as isAuthorized) is true.

Comment: It doesn't have to be such complicated yet (i'm just trying to learn some basic stuff) but thanks for the advice! Also the redirect works perfect and I could pass props to Dashboard, thank you!